# Is there a good way to call .net classes from Java netbeans project?

Tags: c#, java, .net, mobile, netbeans

I have a project that I want to keep the internal business logic in .net assemblies and let the java handle UI work.  Is there a easy way to reference .NET assemblies or .dll in Java Netbeans environment?  Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly I would do the UI in `.net`. Because I think the ui stuff in java isn't very good. I'd sooner do it the other way round.

But communicating between them I would do via services. It's a bigger investment in the beginning but a lot less of a pain to when you're rolling out your application. And it will likely scale a lot better. There is loads of stuff here on SO on writing clients and services in both .net and java.

If you are really sure you still want to use the .net code immediately from your java code there's a thing called [IKVM.NET](http://www.ikvm.net/). Which compiles your java to CLI bytecode. But I don't know if they support java's interface stuff.

Comment: I was looking at the IKVM.NET is this more of a pain in the @$$ or a real solution?  I was still trying to make heads or tales of it.

Comment: IKVM will require a certain amount of effort to get it working. But it is used in production environments out there, so in theory it could be a solution. But like I said a client - server solution is likely a more sustainable one.

Comment: I'm going the monotouch route for mobile dev with IKVM.NET that seems like the best solution at the moment.  But I agree client server would be ideal.

Comment: IKVM was exactly what I needed threw the .dll in the gac and called it a day. Awesome thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can expose business logic through web services (for example REST + JSON). Your UI can be written in Java and it can consume web service, internally implemented in .NET.

The idea is that you separate technologies and let them talk through a well known communication bridge.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm will give it a try.